# Hermitian and Self-adjoint Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, definition

I was wondering what the mathematical distinction between [Hermitian](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=hermitian+operator) and [self-adjoint operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator) were in the context of quantum mechanics? Most texts use this paradigm interchangeably.